# CSS rendered differently in different browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with css rendered differently in browsers, in IE to be specific, thought I could ask here for help, hopefully you can help me out with this : ))

my website is www.artisticworksllc.com if you go to the link, on homepage, below the slideshow there are five images linking to different categories of website.

I tested in Firefox & safari and they look ok, in Internet Explorer they are not aligned, fifth image comes down in IE. When I tested it with IE with compatibility view turned on, the images are aligned but other parts of website are messed up (image galleries for example)

Can anyone help me with this please? what to do? I dont know if this is padding or what is causing it. I know I have to implement some kind of IE hack but I dont know what and how : (

help is much appreciated : ))

Thank you

Comment: For some reason, the last `<li>` is spilling outside the bounds of the 940 px allowed by the parents elements. Try resizing the image until it "fits" once it does, you'll know how many pixels you have to "work with" and that pixel value might match up to the value of another css style you have applied to them. That may help you narrow down the problem to a specific style.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I cant do with that <li> : ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your link to pull in the CSS, put this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Make a second style sheet called ie.css and just change the parts that need to for IE.

You also have the ability to add versions:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul... I didnt know how to do it. One more thing, Will I need to code all the classes in IE CSS file, or shall I just code the classes which are not rendered correctly ? 

Thanks again!

P.S. No Idea, I didnt down vote anything, Why would I down vote any ideas when people try to help me? : ))

Comment: Just the ones that aren't rendered correctly. But it's important that you place the call for the IE style sheet AFTER the call for your regular style sheet. CSS pulls in order, so it has to render your IE classes after it renders your default ones.

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot. I guess the problem is solved : ))  I'll do that tonight. 

Thanks Paul and Thanks Everyone! You guys are great!!!

God Bless

Comment: Don't forget to click the little checkmark to say you've got an answer :)

Comment: yeah. i gave the same answer without giving you the code. why was mine downvoted?

Comment: @albert: I can promise it wasn't me.  I may not agree with the answer, but it is a viable solution. (so +1) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Before going down the crazy path of writing custom CSS per browser (and potentially version):  get rid of the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype and move to one of the strict types. Preferably html 4.01 strict.

This alone will fix the vast majority of your boxing issues.

Some more info on Doctypes:

Read both pages of the following site.  Great links on page 2.
http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=85fee

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

And, for "light" reading: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Basically, all browsers have various degrees of "standards" compliance.  Anything that kicks off "quirks" mode or is "transitional" should be viewed with suspicion.  However, once you understand what a doctype is and your choices around them, then you'll completely understand what's going on for any display differences you do run across.

For me, one of the best ways to learn was to create a simple floating div layout controlled by CSS.  Some div's held images, others had extra long text, all of them had a border so I could see where things were breaking.  I then tried various doctypes and viewed the page in the major browsers.  Sometimes the differences were minor like slighly different default padding or margins; sometimes they were outrageous such as one browser allowing styles to be inherited that another didn't.

We have a decent sized web app (200+ pages) with fairly complicated layout requirements and the ONLY "hack" I've had to implement was to force the image tag (img) to be `display:block;` it looks pixel perfect identical in every browser and we are not using conditional style sheets or performing any type of browser sniffing.

Comment: I thought XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype was more "open" and not "strict" and would be easier to work with, isnt it so? Can you tell me why would it cause problems please?

Thanks for help!

Comment: @Johnathan Bell: "open" in this case means that browsers are free to interpret layout as they see fit.  "strict" means they are standards compliant.  Also, XHTML has been essentially deprecated in favor of HTML 5.  The net result is that when using "transitional" different browsers *may* use their own defaults for things like padding, boxing, etc.  Whereas "strict" means they should conform to w3c specifications.  Just about every "css hack" can be thrown out if you use a strict doctype because almost every browser (IE 6 and up) does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to target versions of ie with conditional comments; using them you can set specific styles for any and all versions of ie to make them look how they should.

Comment: yeah. i gave the same answer without giving you the code. why was mine downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Check you padding and margin attributes for the list elements. Perhaps your size arrangements are right, but since every browser renders styles differently, IE is responding differently.